# how to deploy ExpressJS in TypeScript to Azure?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, express, web-deployment

I am trying to create an Express Server for API service, using this express generator:
[generator-express-no-stress-typescript](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress-typescript)

I can run the Express Server locally using `npm run dev`.
I can run `npm run compile` to create the production build in dist folder.
The the dist folder product package can be started using `npm run start` without issue.

However, **I failed to deploy the app to my Azure server**. I have followed [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash), to deploy the Express.js to Azure App Service using Visual Studio Code. After all steps, when I browse the app it shows `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

Any article or document I can refer to? Thanks for any help.

package.json `scripts` section by default created by [generator-express-no-stress-typescript](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress-typescript)

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "compile": "ts-node build.ts && tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.ts | pino-pretty",
    "dev:debug": "nodemon --exec \"node -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk\" server/index.ts | pino-pretty",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js \"{server, test}/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" --quiet",
    "lint:fix": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js \"{server, test}/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" --quiet --fix",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.ts --exit",
    "test:debug": "mocha -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk test/**/*.ts --exit"
  },
```

Comment: Linux or Windows ?

Comment: my PC is Windows, on Azure I chose Windows too.

Comment: Pls run ‘tsc -v’, then tell me which typescript version you use, because I can’t run successfully by running  ‘npm run start’ on local. I just can run ‘npm run start:dev’.

Comment: my typescript version is 4.3.2

Comment: Can you share your `scripts` cmd in `package.json` ?

Comment: now I tried `generator-express-no-stress-typescript`, I can run it, compile it, run the compiled build without issue. Still after upload to Azure the page cannot be display. attached the `scripts` section in the question. Thanks!

Comment: After a series of tests, I failed. I will start a bounty if anyone with other relevant experience can provide answers.

Comment: Have you checked server logs?

Comment: how are you compiling the code(compile cmd) on the server? try changing (compile to prestart or postinstall) I had same issue on heroku.                                                                                                                                          
Guessing: dist directory does not have permission?

Comment: @RahulSharma On myside, it always show `not fount module `express, dotenv, ... and so on`. And I copy and paste package.json to wwwroot folder, then run `npm install` .  Finally, I can run `npm run start` on kudu site,  it shows running on port 3000. But webapp is not start, from application logs, I can find error about `can't find module `dotenv``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure out what's wrong with my package and deployment. Here I would share my findings.

### Azure require iisnode/web.config to execute the app

when I review [this Microsoft tutorial document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash) again, I found in their sample project, there is a web.config file at the root folder

refer to this link: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config

it say "This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind"

I copied the same file to my project, which my project is generated by this generator: [generator-express-no-stress-typescript](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress-typescript)
What I did to my project:

1. use the generator to generate the sample Express API Server
2. run `npm run compile` to compile the product build into `dist` folder
3. copy the above web.config into root folder
4. modify the content, for path point to `index.js`, change to `dist/index.js`

```xml
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="dist/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    ......
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          ......
          <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/index.js"/>
        </rule>
```

after all, I deploy the app to Azure again, now the log file error message changed. Now it shows something like **"Invalid port number, should be in range 0 - 65xxx"**

### fixing the listing port logic

it seems Azure port number environment is not a number, it is a pipe string:
https://www.geekwithopinions.com/2013/12/09/node-js-and-azure-is-it-a-port-or-a-pipe/

however, the generated index.ts logic, since it is TypeScript, the logic parseInt for the port, and it caused error.

```js
// server/index.ts
......
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT ?? '3000');
export default new Server().router(routes).listen(port);
```

For quick test, I just want to prove how the Express Server could work on Azure, so I don't want to fix the TypeScript logic. Instead, I directly modified the compiled js file which generated by `npm run compile`, the `tsc` generated file `dist/index.js` which to be executed by Azure:

```js
// const port = parseInt((_a = process.env.PORT) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : '3000');
const port = (_a = process.env.PORT) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : '3000';
exports.default = new server_1.default().router(routes_1.default).listen(port);
```

deploy again, and it works now :)